# Why can't I see the character _ while using Nano on Yakuake?

Tags: nano, yakuake

[image]I use Gnu Nano on Yakuake to write a LaTeX-document. Then yesterday I found that I can't see the character _ on the Nano. I know that the characters are there as LaTeX renders the tex-file correctly. Is that a bug in Yakuake or Nano or is there some settings that is wrong in my system?

Here is a demo. The code that looks like \lim {r\to\infty} is really \lim_{r\to\infty}

Comment: Please add a screenshot that shows the issue.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using nano to edit a tex file? Seems an odd choice to me unless nano is just your preferred editor in general.

Comment: @JAB I just learned to use Nano in my first summer job and I have used it since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a problem of the font you're using in Yakuake. Try setting a different one; the property can be found in the profile configuration.

Comment: Thanks! At least the font FreeMono works well in my case.